# SWIFT 2.1 - Get the JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift2

cant get the JSON code of a file "ios.lpofficial.net/iosdata.json" [a link thereeeee](http://ios.lpofficial.net/iosdata.json), i tried to use the NSURLRequest but i doesn't work. And tried to get the source code of the page as usual i stuck on that line:

```
let code = NSString(contentsOfURL: URL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)
```

the problem was in new `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt>` i real can't understand what is that thing.

im using my own hosting with the json file, so may be i need to change something there.

please help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var code: NSString?
do {
    code = try NSString(contentsOfURL: URL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
} catch _ {
    // Handle the error
}
```

You can also do that:

```
let code = try! /*(or try?)*/ NSString(contentsOfURL: URL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```